# Are the Broadcom drivers in any new releases for my Dell with BCM4401 and BCM4311

Tags: 12.04

I installed 12.04 on my wife's Dell laptop to replace 10.04.  The code for the Broadcom drivers is broken and I am a user, not a coder.  Does any available release of Ubuntu have the drivers in place so I can install and run and get my life back after days of thrashing around.  I am willing to do some work, but I am not up to heavy duty command line activity.  Please help if you can with any information.  Thanks in advance.  Matt

Answer (score 0):

The b43 driver is present in the default release, so just add the firmare package linux-firmware-nonfree.  Of course, from a wired connection, but the release ethernet should work out of the box.  You didn't identify the actual pc-id of the 4311, so if that does not work because you have an unsupported chip, then try the wl proprietary driver.

Answer (score 0):

Just use additional drivers, that worked for me!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. A full answer would include instructions about where this option is found and how to use it. Maybe with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Please hook up the ethernet cable. You may safely copy and paste these commands into a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t:

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

Is your device 14e4:4311? If so, please proceed. If not, please edit your question to add the details.

```
sudo modprobe b44
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detatch the ethernet, reboot and both should be working as expected.

The 'Additional Drivers' tool offers the wrong driver for your Broadcom 4311 and blacklists several competing drivers, including, incredulously, your ethernet!

The proprietary Broadcom firmware is never included in the default free and open source Ubuntu install and must be installed afterwards.